# containerized node app wont run on server, but will run in wsl

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, podman

i have two identical folders that hold a nextjs app.

one sits in wsl, the other sits on a server.

when i run the following to have the app in a container:

```
podman run \
            -v /home/mee/dev/abd/:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app \
            -p 3000:3000 \
            --name next.dev node:latest \
            npm run dev
```

it works in wsl:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /usr/src/app/.env.local
event - compiled client and server successfully in 905 ms (190 modules)
```

does not work on the server:

```
> abdn2@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /usr/src/app/.env.local
warn - As of Tailwind CSS v2.2, `lightBlue` has been renamed to `sky`.
warn - Please update your color palette to eliminate this warning.

<--- Last few GCs --->

[14:0x5667d50]    89995 ms: Mark-sweep 483.6 (499.7) -> 479.9 (500.0) MB, 1420.0 / 2.0 ms  (average mu = 0.207, current mu = 0.042) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[14:0x5667d50]    92296 ms: Mark-sweep 484.1 (500.2) -> 480.3 (500.5) MB, 2156.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.129, current mu = 0.063) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb2e180 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa4019e node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xd1fc3e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xd1ffb7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xed93e5  [node]
 6: 0xeea82d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 7: 0xeed55e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 8: 0xeaef7a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
 9: 0x122f3d8 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x1632879  [node]
Aborted
```

now my question is, is it because my webserver isn't hooked up yet - or is this an issue with the app - maybe something that's forgive on wsl but not in the server ( some sort of memory leak )?  if so, is there a way for me to diagnose the issue?

thanks!

edit: in wsl these are the container stats:

```
ID            NAME        CPU %       MEM USAGE / LIMIT  MEM %       NET IO            BLOCK IO    PIDS
b6821569de9f  next.dev      --          493.2MB / 3.135GB  15.73%      4.21kB / 8.393kB  -- / --     23
```

on server:

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         999808 kB


               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             976         342         412           3         221         479
Swap:            511         389         122
```

i will try to upgrade the size

Comment: Looks like your server is out of memory. How much memory does it have?

Comment: You should not mount a code volume in production. Put your code inside on build and run only the image. If possible compile it to statics on build and serve them with something like an nginx image.

Comment: @HansKilian i took the smallest linode.. 1gig ram 25gig storage, 1 cpu core.  just trying to learn... how would i know what the bare minimum i should get?

Comment: @TheFool thank for the advice highly appreciated, im still working on the app so just wanted to see if i could put it online

Comment: @HansKilian that did it, thanks! you can put up the answer if you like